# javascript/jquery: call function on child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

here is my code:

**a.html** :

```
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('#A').load('b.html');
  $('h1').click(function(){
    functionB();
  });
 });
</script>
<html>
 <h1>Title</h1>
 <div id='A'></div>
</html>
```

and,

**b.html** :

```
<script>
  function functionB(){
   alert('funcation B called');
  }
</script>
<p>nothing</p>
```

seems that I can not call `functionB()` from root.
is there anyway to do? thanks

Comment: which child element. those are two different pages!

Comment: You would either have to load the `b.html` (with either Ajax or an IFrame) to be able to access `functionB();`. Alternatively you could place `functionB();` in an External JS File and reference it on both pages.

Comment: What you are trying to do is a bad, bad idea. Nunners' suggestion to put the scripts in a separate (javascript) file is the correct one. If you need to run functionB on both pages, then include the script on both pages.

There is NEVER a good reason to mix HTML and JS together and 'call a function on another page'. It just means your basic design is wrong.

Comment: @Nunners: Suggest you post your idea as an answer... It is a better way of organising this specific example. Rather than another take credit for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I've done wrong:

right b.html

```
<script>
  $('#bContent').ready(function(){
    //do something here
  });
  function functionB(){

    alert('funcation B called');
  }
</script>
<p id='bContent'>nothing</p>
```

wrong b.html

```
<script>
  $('#bContent').ready(function(){
    //do something here
    function functionB(){
      alert('funcation B called');
    }
  });
</script>
<p id='bContent'>nothing</p>
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should abstract the `functionB()` function into a separate .js file and include that file on each page:

Any time you have common code, abstract it into a shared component and call that component from the places where it's needed.

Comment: its my personal suggestion .

Comment: In that case: Please give credit to the commenter that suggested this *before you* :)

Comment: Hi,    I found this is working from the test:
http://wesley.com.hk/test2/         but donno why do not work on the site I actually working on.            I am developing an ajax site with hash natvigation.       each inner page has it's own js functions.         then, i am going to add a 'on hash change' function so to allow user press 'back' of the browser.   so I need to call functions on the inner page so to let it open

Comment: your code is working in me also; the `functionB()` is calling in `A.html` page. are you sure that `b.html` is as exact as you've mentioned here ?